# How do I ignite my torch?

Tags: dark-souls-2

I know this sounds silly and there is probably something that I am obviously missing, but I have looked on several different websites and none of them tell me how to ignite the torch.

I've gotten several pieces of information on what they do and how the timer works and that you can use them to ignite the pyres about the world to give you extra light, but the one piece of information that I just cannot find is how to turn it on.

I checked the help stuff in the menu, but it won't let me hover over the torch timer or tell me how to do it.  My retail copy didn't come with a manual either (I don't know if anyone's did).  And if it was explained during the tutorial, I died jumping down off the ledge near the one of the first pyres you come across.

Do I have to visit a bonfire?  There is no "torch" item in my inventory to equip nor is there a usable item in my consumables.  I've tried every button combination that I can think of as well.

Comment: If you're on PC, walk up to the bonfire, hit toggle (N), then Light Torch by hitting Enter or Shift + Click. Would add this as an answer, but can't.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

If you visit a bonfire or a lit torch in the environment, you use the action button (<kbd>A</kbd> on Xbox 360, <kbd>X</kbd> on PS3, <kbd>Enter</kbd> or <kbd>Shift+Click</kbd> by default on PC) to pull out your torch and light it. At a bonfire, you may need to press the "toggle" button (<kbd>Y</kbd> on Xbox 360, <kbd>△</kbd> on PS3, <kbd>N</kbd> by default on PC) to show the button prompt to light your torch.

When you light your torch, you'll automatically hold it in your left hand, and it will stay lit until you put it away (by switching your left-hand item to something else). If you want to use it again after you've put it away, you'll need to find a bonfire or torch in the environment to light it again.

There is also a consumable item called Flame Butterfly that will allow you to light your torch anywhere by using the item from your inventory.

(And don't feel bad, it took me a couple hours to figure that one out, too.)

Comment: Thanks for this answer.  That process was in absolutely no way self-explanatory.

Comment: If you changed the default settings like me this is still hard to find. The toggle function is the same as the "Wield right weapon two handed" key binding

Answer (score 0):

stand at the bonfire and wait til it says toggle, your other option is light torch. Took me a while to figure that out. Only did it at first bonfire so far.